# Will fractional scaling happen in Elementary 6?

Tags: display, scaling

Will fractional scaling like 1.5 and 1.25 come with base 6 updates? Because Elementary cannot be used on devices with a resolution of 2160 x 1440 (3:2). Changing dconf-editor and font sizes does nothing work. I can't use my favorite distro.

Answer (score 0):

No, but:

> In elementary OS 6, we now scale default widgets spacing, corner radii, etc. with text size, eliminating a lot of that awkwardness. It’s not quite perfect, but it will make elementary OS much more legible for more people without incurring the performance penalty associated with traditional fractional scaling. And we’re happy to have a more first-class experience for those who need larger text.

https://blog.elementary.io/look-and-feel-changes-elementary-os-6/

Comment: Cassidy James mentioned a new flatpak package today. It may be a good solution, but it's definitely not enough. Deepin solved this problem very well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reply above this topic, i've found some bash script relative to X11 fractional scaling, it works but it requires you execute the script on log-on.

https://github.com/burntcustard/x11-fractional-display-scaling